# Matrix form of second order contravariant and covariant tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

In Schaum Tensor Calculus Solved Problems 3.10 and 3.14 the following matrix equivalent of second order contravariant and covariant tensors are made, but without the derivation being explained ($\normalsize{J}$ is the Jacobian and $\overline{J}$ is the inverse Jacobian):

The contravariant Tensor definition is shown in (1) and matrix equivalent shown in (2).

$$\overline{T}^{ij} = \frac {\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^r} T^{rs}\frac {\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^s} \tag{1}$$

$$\overline{T} = J T J^{T}\tag{2}$$

The covariant Tensor definition is shown in (3) and matrix equivalent shown in (4).

$$\overline{U}_{ij} = \frac {\partial x^r}{\partial \bar{x}^i} U_{rs} \frac {\partial x^s}{\partial \bar{x}^j} \tag{3}$$

$$\overline{U} = \bar{J}^{T} U \bar{J}\tag{4}$$

My question is why are the matrix transposes of $\normalsize{J}$ and $\bar{J}$required and why are the transposes in different places (last term in (2) and first term in (4)), given the expressions appear symmetrical in the r & s indices in (1) and (3) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful notation which can be used to help you is, for any $F:$ $$\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j} \equiv F^i{,}_{j}.$$ Now you can see how are the order of the indexes affect your equation, which is very important since tensors are not necessarily symmetric. Your first expresión would read $$ \bar{T}^{ij} = \bar{x}^i{,}_{r} \;  T^{rs} \;  \bar{x}^j{,}_{s}$$ where you can see the role and need of the transpose with $J^j{}_s = \bar{x}^j{,}_{s}.$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Schaum's Tensor Calculus doesn't mention this order dependence or your comma notation or its rules. Do you know of a Tensor Calculus book that explains the 'comma' index order rules you mention ?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see the "role and need for the transpose" - would it be possible to give an explanation ? (As Schaum's 3.10 & 3.14 just said the same thing without explaining why there is a need for the Transpose). I'm missing something basic here!

Comment: The notation is very common in general relativity books and mathematical physics books too. As for the order with indexes, any object with two indexes could be written in a matrix form. How they are written is up to you, for example $$\bar{x}^i{,}_{r} \;  T^{rs} \;  \bar{x}^j{,}_{s}$$ with the definition of $J$ above implies the matrix on the left is presented with two indexes the second of which contracts with the first on the next matrix. The second index of this matrix should contract with the first on the indexes of the 3th matrix, thus the need to use the transpose.